How to Add a Switch to Control Doorbell Ringer
I have a traditional doorbell ringer (pictured) and would like to add a switch or button that allows me to easily enable or disable the ringer. This is important because I have a baby who needs undisturbed sleep. How can I wire a switch into this setup to control the ringer, and what type of switch would be best for this purpose?


There's also the mechanical solution of just muffling the bell...

First consider how often the doorbell actually rings. And whether training the child to sleep through occasional noise would be better.
If you still want to go through with this then a dumb lightswitch from the hardware store will be fine.
Run a pair a of conductors from the ringer to the switch. At the ringer side you disconnect one of the leads from the screw and connect one of the conductors to the screw instead and the other to the lead.
Getting a quieter or smart ringer might also be an option. A bit of felt wedged under the bell will mute it quite a bit.

I live in Berlin in an apartment building. The postman comes nearly everyday and rings to ask if he could leave the parcels for the neighbors. With lightswitch you mean something like this https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51wyxTgbUoL.SL1500.jpg ?

yeah, or a wall/surface mount light switch you'd use for ceiling lights.

And what kind of cable do I need to use? Is 12V sufficient? I found this, which seems to be for a car, but might work as well for my usecase? https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805635091214.html
